# How to clean ctrl+z in linux file?

Tags: linux, redhat, putty

I have copied some text files from windows to redhat machine using putty. When i try to execute the files . I am getting error because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> was added in that file.

I have used this command

```
tr -d '\15\32' <  /path/gems/spec/rms.spec >  /path/gems/spec/rms.spec
```

But the above command is annoying because I have 1000+ `.spec` files under various folder.

Is there any option in linux command to identify the `.spec` files in the directory and clean the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> added in the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That command is also very dangerous since there's no guarantee that the file will be read before it is clobbered.

Comment: I am looking to provide  the file path like  `/path/gems/*/*.spec`. I have tried using `sed` command also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, you can try with:

> ```
> find . -type f -name '*.spec' -print0 | \
> while IFS= read -r -d '' dot_spec_file; do \
> cat "$dot_spec_file" | \
> tr -d '\15\32' | \
> sponge "$dot_spec_file" \
> ; done
> ```

Execute it on the parent directory of your .spec files.

---

***sponge*** reads all its input before write the file; from its manual:

> sponge  reads  standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
>   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening
>   the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and
>   write to the same file.